# Have the Mugiwara pirates ever cashed in a Pirate for a bounty reward?

Tags: one-piece

Is the "Bounty System" in *One Piece* really necessary? I mean I have never really seen anyone get the bounty reward after capturing and handing the Pirate to the Marines.

Is there any episode where someone actually claimed the money after catching some pirates? What I know is Zorro's previous occupation was "bounty hunting", but did Zorro ever get the money?

Are there any episodes in *One Piece* that interpret how the procedure of taking the bounties from Marines work?

Comment: we never really see them receive the money but if you remember Whiskey Peak live because they are bounty hunter we can assume they actually receive some money.

Comment: check out my thread for more information on the bounty system: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49513/how-does-the-one-piece-bounty-system-work?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Zorro received money and lived this way though this was not his intention or occupation, he simply wanted to fight strong guys.

The bounties are based on the level of threat that person is for the world government.

Also if you have a bounty on your head and you kill or defeat another wanted pirate probably wouldn't be a good idea to take it to the marine force and ask for the prize cause you're actually turning yourself in.

Comment: are there ever episodes in one piece that showed how's the procedure of taking the bounties from marine fort ? i havent seen it...

Comment: I'm not sure, but I remember Zoro defeated two pirate brothers but whether the procedure was shown, I can't remember.

Comment: One exception of a pirate turning in other pirates is Law: he delivered the hearts of 100 known pirates to bargain his way in the Shichibukai.

Comment: @solalito and Blackbeard turning in Ace

Comment: Zoro was shown to defeat some criminals based on their bounties... and then offer then to the bartender to pay his upcoming bar tab.  He was not shown directly turning them into the marines.

Comment: @kaine Blackbeard was already in the Shichibukai so he had immunity

Comment: @Henjin No, Kaine is correct. Blackbeard turning in Ace was in his was in the Shichibukai

Comment: @Henjin Turning in ace was what made Blackbeard a warlord but your immunity would not be needed anyways. Blackbeard did not have a bounty at the time he turned in Ace.  He had not made enough of a name for himself yet to warrent one.  In the WG eyes, he might not have even counted as a criminal pirate officially yet.