# Why is Chopper's bounty so low?

Tags: one-piece

Why is the bounty of Chopper so low compared to his crew-mates ?
After the Enies Lobby Arc, all of the Straw Hats received bounties over atleast 1 million, except Chopper. Doesn't the Navy have the common sense that someone worth 100 Berries couldn't have beat up a member of CP9 ( Kumadori ) ?

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [How does the One piece Bounty system work?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/49513/2516)

Comment: It might be worth noting the only other character with a bounty in the same ballpark as Chopper is the Heart Pirates' navigator Bepo whose bounty of 500 is currently the lowest known bounty. This may suggest animals tend to be throw-ins for capturing an entire crew (why even bother hunting a $10 bounty otherwise). Granted Bepo is a Mink and his brother Zepo and the Nox pirates demonstrate that Minks can rack up respectable bounties of their own so it might not be an animal thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, the Navy doesn't realize that the big buff hairy man that fought CP9 alongside the Straw Hats is Chopper, so they just treat him as a mascot.